# Set up persistent point-to-point VPN connection on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, windows, site-to-site-vpn

I have seen [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/56373/server-to-server-persistent-vpn-connection), but it doesn't have a good response and what I am looking for is a little different.

I have a well working environment (New York) with a Juniper router that allows me to establish a VPN connection to it. It works fine.

I also have a rogue Windows Server (Chicago) in a different location that need a stable point-to-point VPN connection, as both environments need to connect to each other over a secure connection without any user involvement. That's why a client based solution cannot work.

The optimal solution would be to establish a Juniper router in Chicago, but that's not possible under my circumstances, so I need a way to set it up directly on the server. Both Chicago and New York need to be able to contact each other over the VPN, so it has to be both ways.

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a IPSEC site-to-site VPN tunnel. There are plenty of documentation out there explaining how to do this, detailing it all here would take too much time.

Comment: Perhaps IPSEC is the keyword I have been missing to find this documentation. I will investigate. Thanks.

Comment: @NielsBrinch IPSEC is the standard way of doing VPN, PPTP is just Microsofts easymode which is insecure and outdated. So yes, I'm pretty sure that this will put you on the right track :-)